# What is the translation of this text?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, tolkien-languages

Need help with this: **what is the translation of this text?**

Also, is it real text, and which of Tolkien's languages is it in?

[image: Image of text in an alternate language]

A Spanish/native speaker gave it to me, so it is possible that the text means something in Spanish.

Comment: Can you provide some context? Where did you find it?

Comment: This is borderline off topic I guess. Translation of anything written in scifi languages could break SE. Is there a meta post about this?

Answer (score 10):

Seems like a Spanish sentence written letter-by-letter using elvish characters (following a custom mode with a few unusual letter conversions):

> ?pu?eres compartir tus
>
> momentos con los mi??os

which according to Google translate should mean more or less *"[?] share your moments with the [?]"*.

The glyphs for the vowels are *almost* the usual ones (as @JeffZeitlin pointed out, the ones for `o` and `u` are swapped), placed on the consonant following it (as in Sindarin).

... or maybe I'm just seeing patterns in random noise :-)

Comment: What you've transliterated as 'c' here is the _closed_ version of the glyph, which is 'hw'; 'c' would have the open bowl. You also appear to have swapped the tehtar for 'o' and 'u', but otherwise you appear to be correct. The first word comes out '?poieres', where '?' is the glyph that I could not identify. What you wrote as 'o?' in the first word is actually a diphthong 'oi', and the '??' in the final word is actually an 's' appended to the 'm', making the word 'misus' (or 'misos', using your swap of the tehtar).

Comment: It is possible that the text mean something in Spanish. A spanish/native speaker gave it to me. So this seems more or less accurate.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin You are right, my suggested transliteration does not follow the correct rules (and I was non consistent with "o"s and "u"s, but I fixed this). My approach was to consider this as a cryptography and to apply the usual rules only *if* they led to something promising: as "momentos" meant something and "mumentus" did not, I stuck with the swapped interpretation of these tehtar. The same goes for the value of the "hwesta" tengwar.

Answer (score 4):

The calligraphic style appears to be similar to that of the inscription inside the One Ring; however, the first character is not identifiable when compared with the [Tengwar at Omniglot](http://www.omniglot.com/writing/tengwar.htm). When attempting to transliterate in either Quenya or Sindarin/Edhellen mode, I got almost-but-not-quite pronounceable nonsense, so I presume that this was just semi-random text meant to look pretty.

[EDIT: Modulo some minor misidentification of some glyphs, lfurini's transliteration actually seems to be close.]

Comment: The first character *could* be "hwesta sindarinwa" ... though this does not help very much!

Comment: @lfurini - I considered that, but (a) as you indicate, it doesn't make the text any more useful, and (b), it wouldn't really be in the style of the rest of the calligraphy.